# Does anyone know what "in which" means in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

The context: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyNYkQvqK48&feature=youtu.be&t=11m42s

The sentence: **"The door only seemed to be open during fire drills in which just about every door in the buildings opens. "**

I think the "in which" means "where", can someone tell me if that's correct?

Comment: I stand corrected. I could have sworn I saw the same question asked yesterday, and a search on 'fire drills' produced two results (one for Andrew's answer).

Comment: First, let's place "only" close to what it modifies:  The door seemed to be open only during fire drills, during which just about every door in the buildings opens.  No, I don't care for "during" in two places in close proximity; but I'm illustrating the meaning of the sentence.  "When" or "at which time" can be substituted for "during which."

Comment: @KateBunting You remember correctly. Apparently the first question has been deleted (along with my comment on it).

Comment: @KateBunting I had exactly the same impression. I could swear this is actually the third time I've seen this question.

Comment: The question was originally posted as https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471035. Since the asker has now withdrawn the question twice (the second time by vandalizing), and the question as it stands is a request for proofreading with no research effort shown, I think it can just be deleted.

Comment: @LesTivers Thank you for your effort. Please avoid
giving answers
in comments.
The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the
question,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 1):

It means "when". When fire drills take place, almost every door in the building opens.

Comment: Would you see a difference between having a comma after *fire drills* and not having one? Perhaps with a comma just about all fire doors being open during all drills, while without a comma there only some drills which lead to all just about all fire doors being  open (including this one).  Listening to the clip, there may be enough of a pause to suggest a comma.